# How do I record Menu in excel with Macro Record?

Tags: macros, context-menu, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working in Excel and I am about to create a macro. I record myself but the macro is not recording when I click on the menu on Excel, only the cells! How to record also the menu clicks I do?

Comment: What menu action in particular are you trying to capture?

Answer (score 2):

The macro recorder does not record all things that you click. It also very much depends on the Excel version. In Excel 2007, for example, the macro recorder did not record anything to do with charts.

You will need to find out what VBA commands do the things that you want to do and then edit the code and write the commands in manually.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016

Comment: Glad you shared that. That does not change my answer.